# Make on rpi Reference to undefined symbol " err_msg "

Tags: compilation, makefile, raspberry-pi2, pocketsphinx

I updated my raspberry Whezzy the version to the version of Jessie which allowed me to install and pocketsphinx sphinxbase with the apt- get command. But when I compile my program I get this error : Reference to undefined symbol " err_msg ".
Can do you help me please ?

Comment: You need to remove system sphinxbase and make sure you install latest pocketsphinx and sphinxbase from sources

Comment: Problem resolv I have remove the old file .so